# How to fill out blanks in Running Total matrix Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am working on Loss Triangle in Power BI where `AccidentYear` are rows and `DevYear` are columns.

The values in the  table are `Running Total` created by measure:

```
Running Total Loss = 
    CALCULATE( 
    SUM(fact_Losses[PaymentAmount]),
    FILTER(ALL(fact_Losses[DevYear]),fact_Losses[DevYear]<=MAX(fact_Losses[DevYear]))
    )
```

Link to get Raw data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dvb6cu1k4vmzkur/ClaimsLloysddd.xlsx?dl=0

Running Total Cumulative Data looks like this:

```
AccidentYear    DevYear Running Total Loss
2012            12          164714.11
2012            24          167727.65
2012            36          172888.65
2013            12          2314247.18
2013            24          4074094.91
2013            36          5247246.06
2013            48          5576930.29
2013            60          6487155.06
2013            72          6899512.68
2014            12          3367220.82
2014            24          4831946.69
2014            36          5741213.36
2014            48          6750204.17
2014            60          8384764.91
2015            12          7624575.21
2015            24          9935018.26
2015            36          11767207.67
2015            48          14653278.99
2016            12          8531229.05
2016            24          11768128.83
2016            36          17178123.28
2017            12          7390158.93
2017            24          12695778.03
2018            12          13136428.25
```

Then I am using matrix visual with `AccidentYear` are rows and `DevYear` are columns.

[image]

For Year 2012 Development Year only goes till 36. 
But I still need to display the last number, which is `172,888.65` in the rest of empty cells.

I tried to utilize `ISBLANK()` but did not have success so far.

The desirable result should look like this:

[image]

UPDATE:
pbix file can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wl1ot9ejgyv8yi3/Loss%20Triangle%20United%20Specialty.pbix?dl=0

Comment: Can you post the raw data in text form, please?

Comment: Updated. Thank you

Comment: Does your raw data not have `PaymentAmount` rather than `Running Total Loss`?

Comment: Alexis, sorry for confusion. You are correct, that was already Running Total data. I shared the really raw data via drop box link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing you can do with the measure itself to get those to show up since no rows exist in the table that match both the `AccidentYear` and `DevYear` in those cells.

In fact, if you set your measure to a constant value of `1`, then your matrix will look like this:

[image: Constant Measure]

The measure will not evaluate in cells where there doesn't exist any data.

---

@Saaru's suggestion is a pretty simple workaround, but here's another option.

Create an independent table to use for your matrix columns:

```
DevYears = VALUES(fact_Losses[DevYear])
```

If you use that for your matrix columns and alter your measure a bit,

```
RunningTotalLoss = 
VAR CurrDevYear = MAX('DevYears'[DevYear])
RETURN
CALCULATE( 
    SUM(fact_Losses[PaymentAmount]),
    FILTER(ALL(fact_Losses[DevYear]), fact_Losses[DevYear] <= CurrDevYear)
)
```

then you'll have a full table.

[image: Full Table]

This isn't upper triangular like yours is, but you can add that logic with an `IF`:

```
RunningTotalLoss = 
VAR CurrDevYear = MAX(DevYears[DevYear])
VAR MaxYear = CALCULATE(MAX(fact_Losses[AccidentYear]), ALLSELECTED(fact_Losses))
VAR CurentYear = MAX(fact_Losses[AccidentYear])
RETURN
IF(
    YEAR(
        EOMONTH(
            DATE(CurentYear - 1, 12, 31),
            CurrDevYear
        )
    ) > MaxYear,
    BLANK(),
    CALCULATE( 
        SUM(fact_Losses[PaymentAmount]),
        FILTER(ALL(fact_Losses[DevYear]), fact_Losses[DevYear] <= CurrDevYear)
    )
)
```

Comment: Trying to understand here: Is the independent table created from the unique values of `fact_Losses[DevYear]` called `DevYear` or `DevYears`?

Comment: @Alexis Its my first time to do Actuarial Loss Report. Loss Triangle represent how claims, both known and unknown, change over time. By arranging the data in this way, it is easy to see the change in estimated losses or development over time.

Comment: I think it would also work if just populate column 48, 60, 72 with the last maximum number for AccidentYear 2012.

Comment: `DevYear` was a typo on my part. Please see my edit.

Comment: @Alexis thank you very much. Logic seems like should be working, but for some reason it displays   the max value starting from DevYear 2012. I shared .pbix file if you could look at it. Thanks

Comment: In your file, it looks like you didn't swap out the `DevYear` on the columns of the matrix visual. You have to use `DevYears[DevYear]` one.

Comment: Thank you Alexis. Its amazing how you did it. I still confused why and how this part of equation works  :) 
`YEAR(
        EOMONTH(
            DATE(CurentYear -1, 12, 31),
            CurrDevYear
        )
    )`

Comment: @Oleg Let's say you're in the `2016`, `48` cell. This formula takes `2016` year and returns the last date before this year, `2015-12-31`, and then shifts that forward by `48` months to get `2019-12-31`. Then, since `2019` is greater than the max year `2018`, it returns a blank.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to implement this logic for month-year break down. User also wants to see monthly development. Still trying.

Answer (score 4):

An easy way out would be to append the following rows to the raw data:

```
AccidentYear DevYear PaymentAmount
2012         48      0
2012         60      0
2012         72      0
```

You can do this by going to `Enter Data`, adding above table and naming it (e.g.) `appendage`. Then go to `Edit Queries`, and append the table `appendage` to the table `fact_Losses` with the command `Append Queries`. Now hit `Close & Apply` and you will have your desired table:

[image]

I admit this is not a nice, scalable solution, so I hope someone comes around with something more fancy