# Trying to achieve triangular net loss matrix in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, data-modeling

I have been trying to work off the answer to the question below. However, I am trying to implement the logic for Month year breakdown. My pivoted columns are a column called con_seasoning, where it count the number of months from the contract start date to the latest snapshot date. I have been trying to replicate the logic in the answer below, specifically the first part of the IF statement, but my data keeps showing up as blank. The con_seasoning column is in its own table and
my main table is called Net Loss, where the rows (month year start date) is located.

[How to fill out blanks in Running Total matrix Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619619/how-to-fill-out-blanks-in-running-total-matrix-power-bi/77476505#77476505)

Comment: Best to share a sample .pbix for this one.  Or you are going to need to share details about your model, expressions etc...

Comment: Ok will do, I will upload a sample .pbix later.

Comment: This is the link to the sample .pbix.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X8hpiT8WulOm5PX15X72FQEkuZq4je1N/view?usp=sharing

I have been placing the mmmm yyyy in the rows of the matrix and con_seasoning in the columns, with a measure in the values. The measure is in the next comment. The issue im running into is the values are showing as cumulative. If there is no data for a MMMM YYYY by a seasoning, it will display blank, when i want it to display the previous value in the row.

Comment: Measure:

Contract Count Default = 
VAR MaxSeasoning = MAX('Atoka Net Loss'[con_seasoning]) //seasoning column

VAR CumulativeCount = CALCULATE(
    count('Atoka Net Loss'[contract_id]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Atoka Net Loss'[con_seasoning]),
        'Atoka Net Loss'[con_seasoning] <= MaxSeasoning
    ),
    OR('Atoka Net Loss'[con_termination_reason_snapshot] = "Repossession",
    'Atoka Net Loss'[con_termination_reason_snapshot] = "Write Off"
    )
)

return
COALESCE(CumulativeCount,0)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a separate disconnected table for your `seasoning` matrix column.

Create a new Calculated table with:

```
Dim Seasoning = SELECTCOLUMNS(
  GENERATESERIES(0, MAX('Atoka Net Loss'[con_seasoning]), 1),
  "Seasoning", [Value]
)
```

Use the `Seasoning` column in this new table for your Matrix column.

Then update your measure to:

```
Contract Count Default = 
  var terminationReason = {"Repossession", "Write Off" }
  var columnSeasoning = MAX('Dim Seasoning'[Seasoning])
  var maxSeasoning = CALCULATE(MAX('Atoka Net Loss'[con_seasoning]), 'Atoka Net Loss'[con_termination_reason_snapshot] IN terminationReason )

  var cumulativeCount = CALCULATE( 
    COUNT('Atoka Net Loss'[contract_id]), 
    FILTER(
      ALLSELECTED('Atoka Net Loss'[con_seasoning]), 
      'Atoka Net Loss'[con_seasoning] <= columnSeasoning && columnSeasoning <= maxSeasoning
    ), 
    'Atoka Net Loss'[con_termination_reason_snapshot] IN terminationReason
  )
  
  return IF(maxSeasoning > 0 && maxSeasoning > columnSeasoning, COALESCE(cumulativeCount, 0), cumulativeCount)
```

This will give you a Matrix like this:
[image]

Comment: So, i want to show the rows that are 0. It has to have a triangular shape. There isnt any contracts with seasoning 17 for May 2023, so there shouldnt be data in that cell. This is the main issue I've ben running into. The first matrix you show above is what I've gotten too, but I need some type of IF function to only show values where there is data underlying

Comment: I guess I misunderstood, I thought you wanted a running count. You only want a running count from the first occurrence to the last occurrence, right?

Comment: Is this more like it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2z5h.png - If so I'll update the answer above:

Comment: Attached is what im looking for;
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15FviDnSEgCCjfBn-vfO594PqFk3qmnf9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Updated answer above (updated the measure)

Comment: the updated measure is only showing months with data that is terminated. i will attach a new photo of what im looking for. This is very finnicky and thought this would be an easy process to convert from excel to PBI, but nothings easy with PBI haha.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zy-d7wa-rtiGKVKVrzvY_wKMlXnPZCQW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You want it like the visual you just shared? Please be clear.

Comment: yes, the latest visual is all the data i currently i have in my actual .pbix file. but the fields are the same in the sample .pbix and actual .pbix files.

Comment: Let me be clear - you want it exactly like https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zy-d7wa-rtiGKVKVrzvY_wKMlXnPZCQW/view?usp=sharing ? How did you create this visual? The updated image in my answer is the same as what you have in your mockup: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15FviDnSEgCCjfBn-vfO594PqFk3qmnf9/view?usp=sharing . Is it the data is wrong or the format is wrong. Again, you need to be clear with detail. Help me help you. With sample pbix you provided, how is the image in the answer incorrect? Highlight what is wrong or needs chainging.

Comment: Sorry, I had gotten mixed up. In my visual, the rows are the "Format Start Date" and the columns are "con_seasoning". Both fields are in the same table 'Atoka Net Loss'. The visual posted is not what i want for the final version, the blank spaces have to show the cumulative count from. For example, the May 2022 & 0 cell should show 0, but it shows blank. I will upload a complete version of what I am looking for.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kl5HOKalt7_xtlTVkilStVGfkUZ63Pa5/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=117948231604592583407&rtpof=true&sd=true

the values in red are what have to show up in the final version of the PBI file. Currently the red values are not present.

Comment: As stated in the Answer, you need a separate table for the columns of the matrix. Please try the Answer (create new table, update matric column, update measure).

Comment: Where did you get up to with this?

Comment: My boss ended up writing a dynamic SQL script that automatically iterates over each month in the dataset and creates a dummy row for each seasoning value where there is no underlying data. Pretty cool concept.